# Bash shell script checker

Tags: arrays, bash, shell

I have to write a script, which gets a text file which contains 9 line and 9 number (1-9) in the lines.
For example:

> 123456789
>
> 234567891
>
> 345678912
>
> 456789123
>
> 567891234
>
> 678912345
>
> 789123456
>
> 891234567
>
> 912345678

I have to check lines and the rows based on the sudoku rules.
Can't be same number in a line or in a row.
So the example is a correct solution.

How to write it in bash shell script?
I cannot use arrays, so what can I do?

Comment: there have been at least 2 other posts this week asking about this problem. search for `[bash] sudoku` (although sudoku may only appear in comments.). Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bash simplified sudoku](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585496/bash-simplified-sudoku)

Comment: @shellter Guess some guys have got a school assignment :-)

Comment: I don't understand that solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution without awk, combining different other tools.
EDIT: This solution works for an inputfile called input and spaces between the digits. See comments about changing this behaviour.

```
echo "Checking 9 lines"
if [ $(wc -l <input ) -ne 9 ]; then
        echo "Wrong number of lines"
        exit 1
fi
echo "Check for correct layout"
if [ $(grep -cv '^[1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9]$' input ) -ne 0 ]; then
   echo "Not all lines are correct, maybe spaces at the end of a line?"
   grep -v '^[1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9] [1-9]$' input
   exit 1
fi
i=0
while read -r line; do
   ((i++))
   if [ $(echo "${line}" | tr " " "\n" | sort -u | wc -l ) -ne 9 ]; then
      echo "Wrong nr of unique numbers in row $i"
   fi
done <input
for j in {1..9}; do
   if [ $(cut -d" " -f${j} input | sort -u | wc -l ) -ne 9 ]; then
      echo "Wrong nr of unique numbers in column $j"
   fi
done
```

Comment: Yes, it worked with bash and an input file called "input".  I should have made a variable with the name of the input file.

Comment: Thank you! Almost good, the second line must be: -ne 8 (I have 9 lines)
And how will it work with az input file which does not contain spaces in the lines? My input file must be like: 123456789 or 147258369 so it doesn't have spaces.

Comment: wc -l gives the number of lines, counting from 1. Do you have an empty line at the end of your input file?  You can make the inputfile variable with `inputfile=input` and `if [  ! -f "${inputfile}" ]` for testing the inputfile (and use `"${inputfile}"` where I use `input`.

Comment: It is fun to look for different ways to check one line without spaces. You should try! Hints: Something with `if [[ "${line}" = *1* ]] && ` or something like `line=$(echo "${line}" | sed "s/${nr}//")` in a loop.